# JQuery.load() or $this->load->view() - refreshing divs in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a few views in divs loaded on my page.

and I have something like that:

```
<div id=header>
...
...
</div>

<div id=content>
...
...
...
<a href="#" class="ref"> refresh extra div </a>

<div id=extra>
<?php $this->load->view('extra.php'); ?>
</div>
....
...
...
</div>


<div id=footer>
...
...
</div>
```

Now I want to refresh my #extra div after some action, for example clicking on the “refresh extra div” link.

```
I was trying to use jquery in a way:
$(".ref").click(function() {    
$('#extra').load(<?php $this->load->view('extra.php'); ?>);
});
```

but it doesnt work - how to do it? How to dynamically refresh divs with views loaded into them?

Thanks!

**@@update**

I have quite long extra.php view file, and jquery.html() gets it only when all file is in the one line (unreadable) is it a way to make jquery.html() to get the whole file on it's form?

It loads:

```
<table><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr></table>
```

but it doesnt't load this:

```
<table>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to try this

```
$('#extra').load('extra.php');
```

instead of `$('#extra').html("<?php $this->load->view('extra.php'); ?>");`

Comment: It doesn't work for me, my extra.php file is in default codeigniter's view directory..

Comment: have you tried `$('#extra').html("<?php $this->load->view('extra.php'); ?>");`

Comment: I updated my question ; ) I have one more simple problem with it, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

And how about passing a "true" as second parameter in order to return the view markup?

```
$('#extra').html("<?php $this->load->view('extra.php', TRUE); ?>");
```